# How to get OpenMP to work with #pragma omp task?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm using OpenMP with Linux terminal. I compile my program with the flag `-fopenmp`. The environment I'm using does support multithreading.

```
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {
        #pragma omp task
            R11Inverted = compute_inverse(r11, half);
        #pragma omp task
            printf("5 I am thread # %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
            R22Inverted = compute_inverse(r22, half);
    }
```

As a simple and minimum test, all I want to do is get `printf("5 I am thread # %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());` to show that the program is running with three threads. Basically `omp_get_thread_num()` should return values either 0, 1, or 2.

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5zdn.png)
The block of code above is called many times repeatedly. However the results every time is showing that threading is not working and the program is only using a single thread (Thread 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the {} around the block of code and also the single clause.

Try the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
{
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp task
               R11Inverted = compute_inverse(r11, half);
            #pragma omp task
            {
              printf("5 I am thread # %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
              R22Inverted = compute_inverse(r22, half);
            }
        }
}
```

> However the results every time is showing that threading is not
> working and the program is only using a single thread (Thread 0).

If you want to check if it being called by multithreads use instead [omp_get_num_threads](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fnum_005fthreads.html), which returns the number of threads which the team.

```
   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
   {
            #pragma omp master
            {           
                printf("Total Threads # %d\n", omp_get_num_threads()); 
            }
            #pragma omp single
            {
                #pragma omp task
                   R11Inverted = compute_inverse(r11, half);
                #pragma omp task
                {
                  printf("5 I am thread # %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
                  R22Inverted = compute_inverse(r22, half);
                }
            }
    }
```

---

If the code above is call recursively then you need to adapt to the following:

```
   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
   {
      #pragma omp master      
      printf("Total Threads # %d\n", omp_get_num_threads()); 
      #pragma omp single
      compute_inverse(...); // First call to the recursive function
   }
```

and inside the compute_inverse function:

```
   #pragma omp task
   R11Inverted = compute_inverse(r11, half);
   #pragma omp task
   {
      printf("5 I am thread # %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
      R22Inverted = compute_inverse(r22, half);
   }
```